# Need to write a predicate to search for a date in a core data object's array property (in my case array of dates)

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I need to fetch an object using Core Data. The object has a property datesArray(Array of NSDate objects stored as NSData) which I use to store array of dates. I need to check if the array contains todays date and then use the object.

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSError * error;
NSArray * fetchedArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.datesArray CONTAINS  %@",[NSDate date]];
for (MyEntity * entity in fetchedArray) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:entity.datesArray];
    [array filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (array.count >0) {
        [_myMutableArray addObject:entity];
    }
}
```

Comment: instances of `NSManagedObject` cannot have an array as a property so your question needs some cleanup. What does that property look like? How is it modeled? Are you actually dealing with a relationship to another object that contains a date? Might be best to show a picture of this part of your model.

Comment: I know that an NSManagedObject cannot have an array as a property. That's why I'm using NSData to store the array and later retrieve it using NSKeyedUnarchiver. That part is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be storing dates like this. You are losing the value of using Core Data. If you have an array of something then that should be on the other side of a relationship which you can then retrieve efficiently from the underlying persistent store.

I suspect that your predicate lacks precision as a date object is down to the nanosecond. If you are looking to match something from "today" then you need to work on something with less precision. Perhaps a string in a specific format or store it as a number and then search within a range (less than X and greater than Y type of search).

Again, storing the actual dates in managed objects makes this question much easier but you are still going to be dealing with a precision problem.